# Performance Monitor monitoring packets received on specific port?

Tags: performance-monitor, network-monitoring

We're using dozens of ports to receive hundreds of UDP connections per second (each connection is one packet) from gps devices. The programs that do the listening are poorly written and don't log any kind of stats. Performance monitor will let us watch the number of packets for an entire nic but we're hoping to see if it's possible to see how many packets are coming in on a particular port.

Can performance monitor do that? Is anything else capable of this without disrupting the network? I think Wireshark could, but it would have to interrupt in order to set itself up as a proxy right? This is a production environment, we don't want to drop a single packet if we can avoid it.

Comment: Wireshark is the right choice. You don't have to interrupt anything once it is installed (WinPcap driver)

Comment: So if WinPcap drivers aren't installed will installing them interrupt the flow of traffic?

Comment: I knew you would ask this. But it is out of my knowledge. All I know is that once it is installed no traffic will be interrupted

Comment: We may just have to forego getting anything more specific than all internet traffic.